# recoding variables out of a reactive dataset

Tags: r, shiny

let me try it again :) :

i wrote a little shiny code where some psychotherapists can do graphical diagnosis of questionaires.

i have different timestamps (messzeitpunkte), where these questionaires were completed. in dependence of these timestamps different datasets are build (f.e):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Individualdiagnostik HSA"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput(inputId = "datensatz", label = "1. Datensatz laden"),                     
          textInput(inputId = "pchiffre", label = "2. Patientenchiffre"),                     
            selectInput(inputId = "messzeitpunkt", label = "3.Messezeitpunkt auswählen",          ### Auswahl Dropdown Messzeitpunkt
              multiple = FALSE, selected = NULL,                                                   
                choices = c("Baseline" = "base",
                  "T0"       = "t0",
                  "T6"       = "t6",
                  "T12"      = "t12",
                  "T18"      = "t18",
                  "End"      = "end")),

server <- function(input, output) {
  datensatz_patient <- reactive({datensatz <- input$datensatz
    infile <- read.csv(datensatz$datapath, header = TRUE, ";", na = -77)
    patient <- input$pchiffre
    subset(infile, Chiffre == patient)})

messzeitpunkt <- reactive(input$messzeitpunkt)

CTQ_dat <- reactive(
  if (messzeitpunkt() == "base") 
    {subset(datensatz_patient(), select = c(Base_CTQ_v1:Base_CTQ_v28))} 
  else if (messzeitpunkt() == "end")
    {subset(datensatz_patient(), select = c(End_CTQ_v1:End_CTQ_v28))} else {})
```

Now i need to recode some variables in my CTQ_dat().

i tried:

```
CTQ_dat <- reactive(if (messzeitpunkt() == "base") 
    {subset(datensatz_patient(), select = c(Base_CTQ_v1:Base_CTQ_v28)) }
  else if (messzeitpunkt() == "end")  
    {subset(datensatz_patient(), select = c(End_CTQ_v1:End_CTQ_v28)) } 
  else {})
(if ((CTQ_dat[5]) == "5") {Recode(CTQ_dat[5], "5=1")}))
```

or

```
recode(CTQ_dat()[5], "1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[7], "1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[10],"1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[13],"1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[16],"1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[19],"1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[22],"1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[26],"1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")
recode(CTQ_dat()[28],"1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; NA=NA")})
```

nothing worked for me. can someone please give me a hint where my mistake is?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat `CTQ_dat()` as a function and not as a data.frame.
The last run line in the function will be the return value of this function.

I altered your function, but cannot test it, since I don't have the data.

```
CTQ_dat <- reactive(
  if (messzeitpunkt() == "base") 
  {
    df <- subset(datensatz_patient(), select = c(Base_CTQ_v1:Base_CTQ_v28)) 
  } else {
    if (messzeitpunkt() == "end")  
    {
      df <- subset(datensatz_patient(), select = c(End_CTQ_v1:End_CTQ_v28)) } 
  } else {
    df <- datensatz_patient()
  }
  if (df[5] == "5") {
    Recode(df[5], "5=1")
  }
  df
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will Try It when I am Home

Comment: Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  /Users/derlu/Box Sync/Uni/M.Sc./Praktikum/Ambulanz/HSA/Studie/teststudie/app_test.R:113:35: Unerwartete(s) 'if'
112:                                   }else {}
113:                                   if

Comment: I changed my code, because your if else statements were not correctly structured. But without (example) data I am still touching in the dark here.